# Problem with c with dynamically allocating an array

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_all(char* array)
{
    int c = 0;
    int increse = 20;
    int number_of_char = 0;

    for (int increment = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; increment++)
    {
        ++number_of_char;
        if (number_of_char % 10)
        {
            array = (char*)realloc(array, increse + sizeof(char));
            if (array == NULL)
            {
                printf("not alocated!");
                exit(22);
            }
            increse += 10;
        }

        array[increment] = c;
    }
    printf("%s\n", array);
}

int main(void)
{
    char* array = (char*)malloc(10);
    if (array == NULL)
    {
        printf("not alocated\n");
        exit(33);
    }
    input_all(array);

    printf("%s\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

So what I'am trying to do is to fill up "array" with getchar. When I try to print it out I get some garbage values at the end (most of the time). I think the problem is that I'am giving out to much space to "array" with realloc but I have no idea how to fix it. I also tried placing all the sizes to 1 in malloc and realloc and increse so that whenever i get a charcter the size of "array" increses but it still did not work.
Anyone have any idea how ot fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you realloc but you don't return the new address

Comment: `for(int increment = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; increment++)` will become an infinite loop if your input stream is closed without ever providing a newline.  You must also check for EOF.

Comment: @Ôrel How am I supposed to do that? Could you at least send me a link, I tried looking online but could not find anything useful.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Well I want to have unlimited number of sentences till '\n' is pressed. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: just `return array;`

Comment: @Ôrel My function is void. And Iam also printing it inside of the void function.

Comment: It's only a bad thing if the input stream ends and your program goes into an infinite loop, continually growing the array until you run out of memory.

Comment: `increse + sizeof(char)` should be `increse * sizeof(char)`

Comment: if you like print with %s format you need put a null byte ('\0') at end of string. declare 'incremet' out of for and initialize it to 0 into for, at end, out of for brackets add "array[increment] = '\0';" and all works.

Comment: realloc can change address of allocated memory if need. if you like print youe array in function main you need get new pointer from your 'input_all' function.

Answer (score 1):

`array` must be null terminated, otherwise `printf` and other c-string functions don't know where the end of the string is at.

`realloc` may not return the same address (although that's not an issue on your PC), you have to use the address of pointer.

You can allocate the whole array `realloc`. If subsequent `realloc` fails then you don't necessarily have to exit, you can print error and return the string which was already allocated.

```
void input_all(char** parray)
{
    char* arr = NULL;
    int size = 0, i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        int c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
            break;
        if (i == size)
        {
            size += 10;
            char* temp = realloc(arr, size + 1);
            if (temp == NULL) { printf("realloc failed\n"); break; }
            arr = temp;
        }
        arr[i++] = (char)c;
    }
    if(arr)
        arr[i] = '\0'; //<- don't forget to terminate the string with 0
    *parray = arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* array = NULL;
    input_all(&array);
    if (!array)
        return 1;
    printf("%s\n", array);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```